# Excel If Then formulas for adding multiple values to a total

Tags: excel-formula

I am working with Excel and want to use If-Then statements to tally values on a separate sheet.  An example would be: If text in cell L1=D, then add value in cell, K1 to a cell A1 in a separate tab that would be an ongoing tally. If text in cell L1=E, then add value in cell, K1 to cell B1, on the separate tab that would be an ongoing tally.

Basically, I have purchased 5000 books. Some of these books are for library A and some are for library B.  I need to pull the costs of each book based on destination and tally them up in a separate sheet.  I need a formula that will keep adding book price to book price in the tallying cell so that I will have a grand total for the location.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use SUMIFS.

In A1 on Sheet2: `=SUMIFS('Sheet1'!$K:$K,'Sheet1'!$L:$L,"D")`

In B1 on Sheet2: `=SUMIFS('Sheet1'!$K:$K,'Sheet1'!$L:$L,"E")`

In English, this translates to:

"In this cell (eg A1) add up all the values in column K on that other sheet (Sheet1).  But, only include cells where the corresponding value in column L meets this criteria (eg is equal to 'D')."